# Insert formula, process and replace by raw value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

What is the best approach to achieve the following:

If a cell in column A has content, then place a formula into the cell in column B in the same row, referencing the cell in column A.

Once the formula has been processed, replace the formula with the raw value that the formula returned.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be able to easily copy a portion of the value in column B, put an array formula in the header of column B that fills the whole column based on what's in column A. The cells in column B will *appear* to contain static values, but they will keep changing dynamically based on what's in column A.

To put static values in column B, use a script that either calculates the values to put in B directly, or puts a formula in column B, flushes, and replaces the formula with its value.